# How to show an image larger that it's container using CSS or Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add a picture to the left side of a text inside of a dark container. But, I want the picture to start from the very bottom of the container and goes through the top of the container. So that the picture appear outside the top of the container. Here is a sketch of what I am trying to create.

[image]

Here is my code

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <div class="container-fluid text-white bg-secondary py-5">
        
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid text-white bg-dark">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-md-row justify-content-md-between">
                     <div class="">
                        <img src="http://clipart-library.com/images_k/person-transparent-background/person-transparent-background-16.png" alt="" class="img-fluid px-5" />
                     </div>

                     <div class="py-3 py-lg-5">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Click here</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
         </div>
```

How can I force that image to show out side of it's dark container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider adding a negative `margin-top` to the `<img>` element's container.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid text-white bg-secondary py-5">

</div>
<div class="container-fluid text-white bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-md-row justify-content-md-between">
      <div style="margin-top: -50px">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/531/1000" alt="" class="img-fluid px-5" />
      </div>

      <div class="py-3 py-lg-5">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Click here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```